# How can i direct to the PDF file generated by clickable notification

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-pendingintent

**Hello, I am making a project where the record contains ID, Name, Status And I have save it as a PDF the data, and its gets a notification after getting saved,
No I wanted to know how can I make that clickable and direct to file.**
Below is the code I tried, but not working

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent. CATEGORY_APP_FILES) ;
    notificationIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filePath), "application/pdf");
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent. getActivity (SheetActivity. this, 0 , notificationIntent ,  0) ;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder
            (SheetActivity. this, default_notification_channel_id )
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable. mcclogo )
            .setContentTitle("PDF saved")
            .setContentText(filePath)
            .setContentIntent(resultIntent) ;
```

Comment: Did you start the project ? and if yes, then let's us know where you have issues. One by time, with some code examples.

Comment: it's good that your app is in progress, but i doubt that you get the purpose of this site. Here we can solve only specific issues(one by one), so if you have one then you were welcome to post it. Means try to narrow down each issues on your app, made a small example showing where is the trouble  and post it. Maybe look how others ask and get answers in order to have a better idea of this site. To know "How To Ask" in order to get the best answers in not a trivial aspect.

Comment: @TraianGEICU thank you to let me know about the actual purpose of this site, 
will post my issue if any